# Correct way to initialize array of boost::scoped_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I have a class with an array of scoped pointers to objects which do NOT have a default constructor.

The only way I've found to "initialise" them is using `swap()` like this:

```
class Bar {
  Bar(char * message) {};
}

class Foo 
{
  boost::scoped_ptr<Bar> arr[2];

  Foo()
  {
    arr[0].swap(boost::scoped_ptr<Bar>( new Bar("ABC") ));
    arr[1].swap(boost::scoped_ptr<Bar>( new Bar("DEF") ));
  };
}
```

This feels a little verbose and clunky. Have I missed a smarter way of doing it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
arr[0].reset(new Bar("ABC"));
arr[1].reset(new Bar("DEF"));
```

Comment: As expected, I'd missed the obvious way. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The biggest problem is that there is no way to initialize an array using the member initializer list here. 
You might want to use a specialized pointer container like [`ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) instead:

```
struct Foo {
    boost::ptr_vector<Bar> bars;    
    X() : bars(boost::assign::ptr_list_of<Bar>("ABC")("CDE")) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a typedef?

```
typedef boost::scoped_ptr<Bar> TBarPtr;
arr[0].swap(TBarPtr(new Bar("ABC"));
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution: use [boost::ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) instead of an array.

<strike>You could also use `std::vector<scoped_ptr>` and fill the array using `push_back`.</strike> Edit: I think this won't work with scoped_ptr.